# Running ReSharper Tests in Parallel by NameSpace

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, nunit, resharper

I am wondering if I can run my NUnit tests in parallel, I'm using the R# test runner and there is the option of running assemblies in parallel.[image]

I have a Test Project with all of the tests and they are all 'grouped' and ordered by `namespace`. Is there any ability to be able to run tests in namespaces in parallel? 
Example of what I mean by 'grouping'[image]

Comment: As far as I know you can only run complete test assemblies in parallel. Maybe splitting your test assembly into two or more independent assemblies is an option.

Comment: I'd rather not go down that route, I guess I'll have to if that is the only option though.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the NUnit console and that gives you some commandline options to run the tests by specifying `TestFixtures`

`nunit /fixture:NUnit.Tests.AssertionTests nunit.tests.dll`

to load only the NUnit.Tests.AssertionTests in the nunit.tests.dll assembly. The name specified after the **/fixture** option may be that of a `TestFixture` `class`, or a `namespace`

I have never personally tested parallel execution with commandline but theoretically it can be done

See [this](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=guiCommandLine&r=2.4.8)

Comment: Unfortunately this would not run the tests in parallel. Unless I ran multiple NUnit console instances.